# Create a directory within a directory in Q kdb+

Tags: kdb

I'm just starting out on learning how to use Q and was wondering how do I create two directories inside the directory that I start q from?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make two directories in a q script, you can use the `system` command in q.  Docs on this command are [here](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/system/)

You could do something like:

```
q)system"mkdir test"
```

which will make the directory `test` in your current directory from which you started q.  You can adjust the system command as needed.

Comment: I'm using windows and have to create two directories and store tables in them.

Comment: You can use `mkdir` on windows too, or `md`

Answer (score 1):

From your comment it appears you don't want to create empty directories, but instead eventually serialize tables inside.

The answer is therefore simple: *don't bother create the directories*! Just write your tables, KDB will take care of the rest.

```sh
$ tree .
.

0 directories, 0 files
```

```
q)$[`;":dir1/foo"] set ([]i: 1 2 3)
`:dir1/foo
q)$[`;":dir2/bar"] set ([]j: "abc")
`:dir2/bar
```

```sh
$ tree .
.
├── dir1
│   └── foo
└── dir2
    └── bar

2 directories, 2 files
```